# How to get an indexPath of selected row Swift4 JSON

Tags: json, swift4, detailview, indexpath

I am trying to get the labels in detail view filled with an information from this sample JSON `https://api.myjson.com/bins/18qzq5`, I am able to populate the tableView, but failing to get an indexPath of the row and in the detailView I am getting an error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The code I have listed below:
* by the way, I am using swift Decoder

```json
[
  {
    "name": "New York",
    "state": "New York",
    "detail": "The largest city in the US"
  },
  {
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "detail": "Second largest city in the US"
  }
]
```

The ViewController of tableView

```
import UIKit

struct City: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let state: String?
    let detail: String?
}

class TableVC: UIViewController {

var citiesList: [City] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonString = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/18qzq5"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: data)

            if cities != nil {
                self.citiesList = cities

            }else{
                print("it's nil")
            }
            print(self.citiesList)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print("error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailTaskVC
        let city = sender as AnyObject as? City
        detailVC?.city = city
}

}

extension TableVC: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return citiesList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = citiesList[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
}

extension TableVC: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: citiesList[indexPath.row])
}
}
```

The DetailViewController

```
import UIKit

class DetailTaskVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!

var city: City!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.nameLabel?.text = city.name //Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    self.stateLabel?.text = city.state
    self.detailLabel?.text = city.detail

}
}
```

Hope you guys can help me out on this, or maybe there's a tutorial online and you guys can point me out, as I've searched a lot and had no positive result.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailTaskVC
    let city = sender as AnyObject as? City
    detailVC?.city = city
}
```

Use `sender as? City` instead of `sender as AnyObject as? City`. You can't cast a struct as AnyObject.

Comment: When I do print(city) in prepare for segue function it brings me this: Optional(HorizonTest.City(name: Optional("Los Angeles"), state: Optional("California"), detail: Optional("Second largest city in the US"))) (it prints information of both cities) . When I do it in DetailVC after selecting any city from tableView I get 'nil'

Comment: Have you changed the double cast ?

Comment: Yes, I did as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Try using `var city: City?`

Comment: Console prints exactly the same as several minutes ago. In detailVC where print(city) is, the xCode gives me a warning "Expression implicitly coerced from 'City?' to Any".